# UIView won't move correctly on ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

```
@IBOutlet var box: UIView!
var lastLocation:CGPoint = CGPointMake(200,400) //arbitrary value that will change

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    box.center = lastLocation

    lastLocation = box.center
}


@IBAction func detectPan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    var translation  = sender.translationInView(self.view!)

    box.center = CGPointMake(lastLocation.x + translation.x, lastLocation.y + translation.y)



    println(box.center)

    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)

    {

        lastLocation = box.center
    }
}
```

Whenever the code receives a pan gesture the box will move appropriately, but on viewDidLoad() box will not reposition to the given location. In IB it is set to the top left corner and last location will be changing, so I cannot simply move box in IB. How would I make it so that on viewDidLoad box is moved to the correct position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your subviews are laid out out *after* `viewDidLoad`, so if you set your IB subview's position in `viewDidLoad` it will then be repositioned to its frame in the storyboard before the view appears. So I'd recommend moving the code in your `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` then add a dispatch_once block or a conditional to ensure that the code is only run the first time `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called, ex:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    func doOnce() {
        struct Token {
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Token.token) {
            self.box.center = lastLocation
            self.lastLocation = box.center
        }
    }
    doOnce()
}
```

or

```
var subviewsLaidout = false
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if subviewsLaidout == false {
        subviewsLaidout = true
        box.center = lastLocation
        lastLocation = box.center
    }
}
```

Comment: That was perfect! Thank you so much! I have been working on this all weekend to no avail.