# Save coordinate or update frames

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, cgpoint

I'm making an application which use  `gestureRecognizer` to drag drop some `view` with touch. However news positions are not saved and i really don't know how to get it.
firstly, i use this `gestureRcognizer` to move my `view`:

```
func glisserDeposerNote(sender : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let note1 = sender.view!
    let touchCoordinates = sender.locationInView(self.scrollview)
    note1.center = touchCoordinates
    self.viewnote1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
}
```

Secondly, I tried to convert `CGPoint` to `NSData` but i don't know how to save it after that:

```
let points = touchCoordinates
let pointObj = NSValue(CGPoint: points)
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(pointObj, forKey: "coord1")
```

But this make crash when i try to move the view. I noticed it's because the `defaults.setObject...` but I really don't know why.

Comment: Try setValue instead of setObject.

Comment: don't work, crash again  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the CGPoint is not supported value for user defaults. Try converting it to string and then back. You have the tools for those. Example:

```
let pointValue = NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPoint(x: 0.1, y: 1.0))
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(pointValue, forKey: "coord1")
let point = CGPointFromString(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("coord1") as! String)
```

Comment: thanks, this code don't crash my app, but the position is not saved. 
However I set it in viewDidLoad: 
      ` let pointsaved = CGPointFromString(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("coord1") as! String)`
       ` note1.center = pointsaved`

Comment: You must call synchronize on user defaults at some point for them to be saved. You may do that after you set them in your case but generally try to do it when it makes sense due to possible performance issues.

Comment: Also try to avoid force unwrapping (the !-s).

Comment: i noticed the defaults is good, and save very well the position. but the view always come back to it initial place when I launch my application again. ( the defaults is even so good with the "old" position ) 
Maybe i have tu update the frames??

Comment: Some code would help on how you are setting a view position. And if you have some constraints. Generally you should use view did load, did appear and will appear to set the coordinates of the view from the user defaults. View will layout subviews might interest you as well.

Comment: i juste have to set it like that? : 

` override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("coord1") != nil ) {
        self.viewnote1.center = CGPointFromString(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("coord1") as! String)
        }
    }`

Comment: That could work as long as you are sure viewnote1 is already constructed or it might crash. The same thing may be added into view did load and the view will appear would need an if statement "if let viewnote1 = self.viewnote1..."

Comment: i tried 'viewDidAppear' but the changing position take 2 second so we see move it

Comment: That is why you put it inside multiple methods.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that : 
[UIView won't move correctly on ViewDidLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29065456/uiview-wont-move-correctly-on-viewdidload)

So I have to use `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: It should move correctly in view did load but it must be without constraints, usually generated programmatically. Another way is to to set the leading ant top constraint for the view and manipulate the constraints instead of setting the view frame/center. Or yet another to set the view transform to be a translation generated from the point.